Thunderbird - How to diasble .ics file UID duplicate check?
The .ics calendar appointment file format includes a field UID, which is SUPPOSED to be a unique ID.
However, Microsoft, among other entities, will issue .ics files for different appointments but with the same UID. They consider different sessions of a topic to be the same UID. Grr...
Thunderbird email client throws an error when it encounters these, as it should. (Microsoft slopp/laziness...but I digress...)
How can Thunderbird email client be configured to IGNORE the error created by duplicate UID field values so the .ics files can be imported?

Workaround: edit the booking.ics file and delete the line starting with UID, then import it to Thunderbird with
thunderbird booking.ics
